# Count Unique Values in Found Set

Tags: filemaker

Firstly please allow me to explain what I am trying to achieve. I have a found set of about 100 records, each record has a SKU number (serial) now out of the 100 records, some records have the same SKU, so of course there is less than 100 unique SKUS.

I want to know how many times a SKU appears within the found set. NOT the total number of unique SKUS, but more like how many times each SKU appears individually.

So for example I could have the SKU - 123456 - which appears twice in the found set, so the value for that should be 2, as there are 2 instances of that SKU in the found set.

So just to reiterate, I do not want the total number of unique SKU's in the found set, but more to know how many times each individual SKU appears within the found set.

I have tried many things but keep ending up with the total unique values which is absolutely no use to me.

Thanks

Comment: The answer depends on what do you need this information for. The simplest way to *display* it is to sort the found set by SKU and show it it in a list layout with a sub-summary by SKU part (and probably no body part). Place a summary field that counts the records in the sub-summary part and you're done. If you need something else, then clarify - and also state your version.

Comment: Basically, we have a list of orders for the day. Lets say 100 orders are on the list from 100 different people. Each item has a SKU code, so lets say "Pink Socks" would be '00000-PNK-SKS'

In a list view each record shows  a customers name etc, with the item code along side. I want to create a new field or something next to the item code, that will tell me how many times the exact same item code is in the found set.

So the SKU 00000-PNK-SKS might have a 4 next to it, indicating that that SKU code appears 4 times within the found set.

Comment: Are you sure you prefer to display the number "4" four times, rather than just once above or below (or instead of) the 4 records? Also, can you sort the records by SKU for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on [michael.hor257](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3016153/michael-hor257k)'s idea, you can use the GetSummary function to achieve your desired result.

---

Sample field definition:

[image: Sample field definition]

---

After sorting your found set on SKU, this will produce the following result:

[image]

Comment: Provided the records are sorted by SKU.

Comment: Yes, as i mentioned.

Comment: Sorry I missed that - but it's worth stressing.

Answer (score 0):

use ExecuteSQL filemaker native function to achieve this easily. here is FileMaker article that gives a very good insight:

http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3423/~/counting-the-number-of-unique-values-in-a-field

Comment: The question is about counting unique values **in a found set**. That's not possible using `ExecuteSQL()`, unless you replicate the find criteria within the SQL query (and this requires you to know what the find criteria were).